# jQuery - how to wrap following elements?

Tags: jquery

How would I go about using wrap() to wrap following elements inside a `<div>`?

For example:

```
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr> 
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="main"></tr> 
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>

etc
```

I'm wanting to wrap a `<div>` around the tr, so the result would be:

```
<div>
    <tr class="main"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
 </div>
<div>
  <tr class="main"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</div>
<div>
  <tr class="main"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</div>
```

Comment: That'd result in invalid HTML markup... `TR` can only by child of `table, thead, tfoot, tbody, template`

Comment: How to can bind `<tr>` to `<div>` it must have `<table>` tag

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just do not know what to do. I need some wrapper instead of divs.

Comment: @Evelina Explain why would you need to wrap these TRs inside any container?  And btw, are these `tr` set inside a `table` at least?  Otherwise, don't use `tr` elements

Comment: The task is to close and open that divs.

Answer (score 2):

The resulting markup is not a valid since permitted parent elements for `tr` tags are `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` element.

Anyway, you can achieve the result by using [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) method.

```js
// get all tr with main class and then
// iterate over them
$('.main').each(function() {
  // get elements upto next `.main` element
  $(this).nextUntil('.main')
    // include current element
    .add(this)
    // wrap with div
    .wrapAll('<div/>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="main"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr class="main"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr class="main"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Pranav )

Answer (score 0):

Answer # 1: As you expected

```
var parent = $('<div>');
$('tr.main').each(function() {
  var child = $('<div>');
  child.append($(this).nextUntil('tr.main'));
  parent.append(child);
});
```

Answer # 2: Wrap with a table inside the div to avoid invalid mark up.

```
var parent = $('<div>');
$('tr.main').each(function() {
  var table = $('<table>');
  table.append($(this).nextUntil('tr.main'));
  parent.append(table);
});
```